# Adding attribute/field to and array

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8, angular9

I am working on an angular app. I have data as follows.

```
data = [
{
  "sampleData": [{
    "id":"1"
  }],
  "status": "completed"
},
{
  "sampleData": [{
    "id":"1"
  }],
  "status": "not completed"
},
{
  "sampleData": [],
  "status": "completed"
}
]
```

Above one is the sample array.. Like this at run time my array can 200-300 records.
I want to add a attribute/field "category" to each element on the basis of following condition.

- if length of sample data is greater than 0, then check for status. If status is completed than attribute/field "category": "completed" will be added. If status is not completed than attribute/field "category": "not completed" is added.
- If length of sample data is equal to 0, then "category": "on hold" attribute/field is added to array.

So, above array after manupulation should look like as follows:

```
data = [
{
  "sampleData": [{
    "id":"1"
  }],
  "status": "completed",
  "category": "completed"
},
{
  "sampleData": [{
    "id":"1"
  }],
  "status": "not completed"
  "category": "not completed"
},
{
  "sampleData": [],
  "status": "completed"
  "category": "on hole"
}
]
```

Similarly I can have 200-300 elements in an array at runtime and I need to add category to each and every element on the basis of above condition and make a final array. How can I do it in a good and efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the array and check whether the item's `sampleData` property length is greater than `0`, and if so, set the item's `category` property to the item's `status` property. Otherwise, set it to "on hold".

```js
const data = [{
    "sampleData": [{
      "id": "1"
    }],
    "status": "completed",
  },
  {
    "sampleData": [{
      "id": "1"
    }],
    "status": "not completed"
  },
  {
    "sampleData": [],
    "status": "completed"
  }
]


data.forEach(e => e.category = e.sampleData.length > 0 ? e.status : "on hold")

console.log(data)
```

The same logic can be implemented if you don't want to mutate the original by using `Array.map`:

```js
const data = [{
    "sampleData": [{
      "id": "1"
    }],
    "status": "completed",
  },
  {
    "sampleData": [{
      "id": "1"
    }],
    "status": "not completed"
  },
  {
    "sampleData": [],
    "status": "completed"
  }
]


const res = data.map(e => ({ ...e,
  category: e.sampleData.length > 0 ? e.status : "on hold"
}))

console.log(res)
```

With an `if` statement ([as per OP's request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69654841/adding-attribute-field-to-and-array/69654861?noredirect=1#comment123120318_69654861)):

```js
const data = [{
    "sampleData": [{
      "id": "1"
    }],
    "status": "completed",
  },
  {
    "sampleData": [{
      "id": "1"
    }],
    "status": "not completed"
  },
  {
    "sampleData": [],
    "status": "completed"
  }
]


data.forEach(e => e.category = e.sampleData.length > 0 ? e.status : "on hold")

console.log(data)
```

Comment: could you please also given an example how I can add similar attribute to each element using if.. else if. Please keep the above example as well. I just want to try to both ways

Comment: @Rahul I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.map()`:

```
function addCategory(source) {
  return source.map( item => ({
    ...item,
    category: item.sampleData.length === 0
      ? 'on hold'
      : item.status === 'completed'
      ? 'completed'
      : 'non completed';
  });
}
.
.
.
const withCategory = addCategory( getMeSomeSourceData() );
```

That's about as easy as it gets.